# git pull and new java files are created in local directory, but not showing up in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

I ran a git pull via the command line and new files were created.
Eclipse does not show them.
I have restarted and also ran fetch all changes in the EGit.

Answer (score 0):

Right click project folder and click Refresh.